# MySQL list users and their groups

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat, concatenation

In MySql database I have table `user`

```
user_id | user_name
--------+----------
1       | Joe
2       | Anna
3       | Max
```

Table `group`

```
group_id | group_name
---------+----------
1        | Red
2        | Blue
3        | Green
```

Table `group_member`

```
group_member_id | user_id | group_id
----------------+---------+---------
1               | 1       | 2
2               | 3       | 2
3               | 1       | 3 
3               | 2       | 1
```

So... Member of the Red group is Anna, member of the Green gorup is Joe and members of the Blue group are Joe and max.

How can I get the list of users and their groups

```
User  | Group
------+------------
Joe   | Green, Blue
Anna  | Red
Max   | Blue
```

Comment: group is a keyword please alter the table name group to some else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.group_name)
FROM `user` u
inner JOIN group_member gm on gm.user_id = u.user_id
inner JOIN `group` g on g.group_id = gm.group_id
group by u.user_id
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get it done using the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function of MySQL. Note that this makes your query non-portable (since using MySQL extensions):

```
SELECT user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(group_name)
FROM user
JOIN group_member USING (user_id)
JOIN group USING (group_id)
GROUP BY
       user_id
```

I've assumed you have reasonable primary/unique keys on the tables (e.g. a given user name cannot be listed twice in the same group).

Comment: +1 Note `GROUP_CONCAT` has a max length defined by [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). It defaults to 1024 but can be changed. So if your data looks like it's being truncated, that's why.

Comment: @MikeB: Good point. Though if that gets to be a problem, then the listing is better generated in application code rather than DB IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select u.user_name as users, group_concat(g.group_name) as groups
from `user` u 
join group_member gm on gm.user_id = u.user_id
join `group` g on g.group_id = gm.group_id
group by u.user_id;
```